# Is "how to do it" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

If it is, then what is the verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How* used with an infinitive means *in what way or manner*, *by what means*.

> He showed me how to adjust the focus.
>   He did not know how he ought to behave.
>   How does it work?
>   —The New Oxford American Dictionary

> He showed me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this is an [infinitive phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitivephrase.htm) turned into a question.

As such, the verb would be *"to do"* in the phrase *"to do it"*. However, I'm not sure if and how that changes with a *"how"* in front of it.